# NSDate from stange looking string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I have an NSDictionary with the value for date as:
 "Date":"/Date(1314313200000+0100)/",
How can I turn this into an NSDate as it contains strings lie "Date": and / ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1314313200000 is milliseconds since the epoch-date (1970-01-01), and 0100 is the timezone. You need to parse this info out from the string and build a date from it. The `NSScanner` class is a good fit for parsing information out of strangely formatted text.

```
// Init a scanner with your date string
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"Date:/Date(1314313200000+0100)/"];
// Skip everything up to a valid numeric character
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]
                        intoString:NULL];
// Parse numeric value into a 64bit variable
long long milliseconds = 0;
[scanner scanLongLong:&milliseconds];
// Create a date instance from milliseonds sinve 1970-01-01
NSDate* date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:milliseconds / 1000.0];
```

If the time-zone is also important just skip the `+` sign and parse a new number.