# Convert Date( 934146000000+0300) into NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I get the birthday by parsing the xml. In

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser didEndElement
```

method ,I convert the value of the `<birthday></birthday>` element into NSDate but it returns /Date(934146000000+0300)/:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentStringValue];
```

How can I convert it into NSDate to be able to converting into NSString?

Comment: And are we suppose to guess how did you come up with that number?

Comment: What date are you expecting it to be?

Comment: looks like milliseconds since 1970. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038117/nsdate-from-stange-looking-string/7038429#7038429

Comment: Yeah, but it's wrong at the moment. Too many zeros.

Comment: I expect it to return more logical format like 13-8-06 10:53:54 +0300

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're retrieving the value from a long var.

It currently refers to Mon, 29 Nov 31571 00:00:00 GMT

If you remove three 0s from the end it makes sense...

934146000 = Sun, 08 Aug 1999 21:00:00 GMT

You also need to fix the formatting. The format dd-MM-yyyy will not be able to understand 934146000.

You can do something like...

```
CGFloat dateValue = 934146000;

NSDate *theDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:dateValue];
```

This should get the correct date.

But like I said, you need to sort out the value you are getting first.

Comment: @karim This is not true for me. Because the true birth year is 1999 but it gives 1970. But thanks anyway

Comment: @user3065761: Then you are doing something wrong. The above code gives the date `1999-08-08 21:00:00 +0000`. You would get 1970 if `dateValue` is zero.

Comment: Ok like you said It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are getting the value from Java or C#, as current time in millisecond.
In Objective C, NSDate expect the time as second, not in millisecond. So you have to divide it by 1000.

```
NSDate * dateOfBirth = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[recvDate floatValue]/1000.0];
```

You can use something like below, but you still need correction for the millisecond to second value.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ";
    NSDate * date = [formatter dateFromString:str];
```

Comment: This is not true for me. Because the true birth year is 1999 but it gives 1970. But thanks anyway